# Making asynchronous requests within a Node.js server error:"TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_implicitHeader'"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, server

So what I was trying to do was basically make a server that would receive a request, make a new request, receive the new response, and then relay that to the original source.

Here was my code:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write('on');
getSummonerId(response);
});

server.listen(9000);

console.log("Server running!");

function getSummonerId(cb){
    request('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + 'someones-name' + '?api_key=mykeygoeshere', function(request, response, body){
        cb(JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

When I did that, I got `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_implicitHeader'`.

Upon further searching through the tome of googel, I found these:

https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/5597

[How can I properly implement the nodejs Stream API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963873/how-can-i-properly-implement-the-nodejs-stream-api)

I think it might be the problem I'm having, but I'm having trouble translating the context of the original question into the context of my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I think there are multiple issues here, but the big one is that your passing the `response` *object* into your `getSummonerId()` function as a callback, but it's not function, it's an object. How about trying something like this:

```
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');

var server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    // response.write('on');  // why do you have this?
    getSummonerId(function(data) {  // notice that we pass in a function, but keep response handling up here
        response.end(JSON.stringify(data));  // HTTP responses must be strings
    });
});

server.listen(9000);

console.log("Server running!");

function getSummonerId(cb){
    request('https://na.api.pvp.net/api/lol/na/v1.4/summoner/by-name/' + 'someones-name' + '?api_key=mykeygoeshere', function(request, response, body){
        cb(JSON.parse(body));
    });
}
```

Comment: Ah!  I accidentally didn't type "response.end" on Stackoverflow even though I was using it in my code, but your answer solved my problem anyway.  I think it was because I was just passing non-string data into response.end().  Thanks a ton!  :)  And woo Hobbes(dat avatar)!